# How to check Phoenix (Elixir framework) installed version?

Tags: elixir, version, phoenix-framework

I would like to check `Phoenix` framework version from the command line like I check for `Elixir (elixir -v)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to do it with

```
# for >= v1.3
mix phx.new --version

# for < v1.3
mix phoenix.new --version
```

after navigating to the folder containing the phoenix app. I got the cue from [here](https://elixirforum.com/t/how-can-i-check-phoenix-version/1901). Hope it helps someone facing the same query.

In case, you already have older version of `phx.new`, you can try

```
mix local.hex
mix archive.install hex phx_new
```

commands to upgrade `phx.new` installer

Comment: Just as a heads up, the `phoenix.*` tasks are deprecated in v1.3. This may still work for now, but you will want to use `phx.*` tasks going forward.

Comment: @JustinWood Thanks for the info. I have updated the answer with this info

Comment: It is actually 1.3+ where you would want to use the `phx.*` tasks.