# How can I check the version of Apache Phoenix from its command line interface?

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, apache-phoenix

How can I check the version of Apache Phoenix from its command line?

I tried googling for this info but I don't find anything useful.

But I guess there should be some command (or say `SELECT` statement) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the command, but you can look into the /lib folder of Hbase. 
You should find the Phoenix JAR and its version.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but the answer doesn't sound good at all (for several reasons).

Comment: What does that even mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
mix phoenix.new --version
```

you can refer this link
[How to check Phoenix (Elixir framework) installed version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772332/how-to-check-phoenix-elixir-framework-installed-version)

Comment: I believe the requestor asks about another Phoenix. The one from Apache.

Comment: Yes, Apache Phoenix, the HBase based relational database.